# Openlayers 3 geojson vs vector source

Tags: javascript, vector, dictionary, openlayers, geojson

I have just started using OL3 in my application and I see that there is (at least) two ways of drawing features on the map; ol.source.Vector and ol.source.geoJSON.

Except for syntax, what are the advantages/disadvantages using one over the other? What about performance? As far as I can tell, I can draw both lines and points with both, and that is really all I need.

My data is not in geoJSON format, so I would have to convert the data anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use an `ol.source.GeoJSON` if the data you want to display is encoded in GeoJSON. There are also vector sources for other formats, `ol.source.KML` for example.

If you use a specific format for your vectors or manually create vector features using `new ol.Feature(...)` then use the base class, namely`ol.source.Vector`. This is the most flexible, and the one one will use in most cases IMO. Instances of that class expose methods like `addFeatures`, `addFeature`, `removeFeature`, `clear` that you can use to add/remove vector features to/from the vector source. It also exposes methods to "query" the source. Check out the docs!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with ol.source.Vector as you suggested!